# Tilt hyperplane through origin such that all vectors which were in the hyperplane are now on the same side of the hyperplane

Tags: geometry, inequality, vector-spaces, vectors, convex-geometry

We have a hyperplane through the origin in N dimensional space and T vectors in this hyperplane.

I want to proof that if the T vectors are linearly independent (maximal N-1) than I can tilt the hyperplane such that all vectors are on the same side of the hyperplane (and not in the hyperplane anymore or one vector is on the other side). Here an example in two dimensions:

[image]

If the vectors are linearly dependent (N or more vectors are now in the hyperplane) this is not true in general:
[image]

If I tilt this hyperplane, the vectors are on two different sides.

Can anyone help to prove that in N Dimensions?

edit:

Let $\vec{x}$ denote any non-zero vector orthogonal to that hyperplane. Than I want to show: $$\exists \vec{x}: \vec{x} \cdot \vec{r}_k \geq 0 \quad \forall k=1...T \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \exists \vec{x}': \vec{x}' \cdot \vec{r}_k > 0 \quad \forall k=1...T$$

And this is only true if the vectors $\vec{r}_k$ are linearly independent in the hyperplane. I want to show it for general vectors $\vec{r}_k$ with the only property that in N dimensions N or fewer vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $A$ denote a matrix whose columns are the vectors $r_1,\dots,r_T$. Let $x$ denote any non-zero vector.  We find that the hyperplane orthogonal to $x$ satisfies the requirement if and only if $r_k^\top x$ has the same sign for all $k = 1,\dots,T$.

In other words, it suffices to show that there exists a vector $x$ for which the vector $A^\top x$ has either all positive or all negative entries.

---

**Further Hint:** Show more specifically that there exists an $x$ such that we have $r_k^\top x = 1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @EmmaVisser I don't understand your fixation on "tilting" the hyperplane. Surely, it's enough to show that we can find a hyperplane such that all vectors lie on the same side. In general, it is possible to take any two hyperplanes and "tilt" one to produce the second, but it doesn't look like there is any reason to talk about the hyperplane that contains least one of the vectors

Comment: @EmmaVisser The second question there is the more important to answer. In your question, you ask about the statement "if there is a hyperplane for which each vector lies on a single side or is contained by the hyperplane, then there is a hyperplane for which each vector lies on a single side." I am telling you to prove that for linearly independent $r_k$, there **always** exists a hyperplane for which each vector lies on a single side. The implication that you are trying to prove trivially follows.

Comment: @EmmaVisser I am not saying that the overall question is trivial, I am saying that we can avoid thinking about the confusing implication that you have written. As for "how to show this," that's what my hints are about. The second hint leads to a system of equations, and you must argue that this system of equations has a solution.

Comment: There is no need for Farkas' lemma. What I was trying to get you to see is that $A^\top$ is a matrix with full row rank, which means that for any $b$ (such as $b = (1,\dots,1)$), $A^\top x = b$ has a solution.

Comment: As for the proof that you did write, I don't understand when you say that there is a hyperplane dividing the zero vector and the cone. I would say that the zero vector is an element of the cone, so there can be no such hyperplane

Comment: @Emma Glad to help!